# What's the maximum value for an int in PHP?

Tags: php, integer

Ignoring the special libraries that allow you to work with very big numbers, what's the largest int value you can store in PHP?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is
> platform-dependent, although a maximum
> value of about two billion is the
> usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
> PHP does not support unsigned
> integers. Integer size can be
> determined using the constant
> PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using
> the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP
> 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.
>
> 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit.

Comment: Well, on amd64 linux, which is quite common nowadays, its 9223372036854775807 (2^63-1)

Comment: That's a lot of digits - there's the first reason I can think of to ever choose AMD over Intel when shopping for a dedicated server. :)

Comment: @karim79, I think it's due to the arch being 64-bit, not it being AMD.  =]

Comment: AMD64 is one name of the 64-bit architecture used by both AMD and Intel these days.  Other names for it include x64 and Intel 64.  As strager says, nothing to do with it being AMD

Comment: My windows XAMPP echo's 2147483647 . I had AMD Athlon X2

Comment: @Vova Popov,  Yeah I believe that for some reason if you're running php on windows it's forced into using the 32 bit int even though you have a 64 bit machine.  This bug has been a headache on my current project.

Comment: @Raymo: Probably has a lot to do with how big your compiler considers a `long` to be.  If it's compiled for a 64-bit CPU, but with a compiler that still considers `long` to be 32 bits...

Comment: Since PHP 7.0, integers are 64-bit on 64-bit Windows: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - have updated the answer to reflect the additions to the manual

Comment: @Ryall : What does exactly mean by **"Unsigned Integers"** in the statement **"PHP does not support unsigned integers"** from the above paragraph taken from the PHP manual? Would you please explain me regarding specifically to PHP? Thank You.

Comment: @SerialKisser I'm not the original poster, but unsigned integers are integers with an extra bit available to them, because they don't store +/- (the number is always positive). In PHP all integers are signed (can be positive or negative).

Comment: @VovaPopov yeah that's why it's AMD64 and not Intel64 (AKA: Itainium) - because it runs 32 bit software too :)

Answer (score 105):

**32-bit builds of PHP:**

- Integers can be from **-2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647** (~ ± 2 billion)

**64-bit builds of PHP:**

- Integers can be from **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** to **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** (~ ± 9 quintillion)

Numbers are inclusive.

*Note: some 64-bit builds once used 32-bit integers, particularly older Windows builds of PHP*

Values outside of these ranges are represented by floating point values, as are non-integer values within these ranges.  The interpreter will automatically determine when this switch to floating point needs to happen based on whether the result value of a calculation can't be represented as an integer.

PHP has no support for "unsigned" integers as such, limiting the maximum value of all integers to the range of a "signed" integer.

Comment: Interestingly, in 32-bit builds *floats* can retain integer accuracy to higher values than ints - floats can be used for integer values up to 2^53 + 1, significantly higher than the 2^31 - 1 of ints.  In 64-bit builds this is reversed because floats are the same precision but ints are now up to 2^63 - 1.

Comment: > *PHP has no support for "unsigned" integers as such* 

This means that the maximum value of an `unsigned long` cannot be represented in PHP with an `int`, whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit. Also, a Javascript `number` can represent a maximum integer value of 53 bits, due to that language combining floats and ints in a single `number` type. So when you are designing a schema, it can make sense to take into account that the maximum integer value that can be represented on most systems is signed 53-bit and not (signed or unsigned) 64-bit.

Comment: I think Javascript is relevant here because the `number` limit bleeds into JSON, which also cannot represent integer values larger than 53 bits.

Comment: That 53 bit significance comes from IEEE754 which is also the standard for floating point numbers built right into processors.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that many languages define specific integer types which are not internally stored as double precision floats. This gives those languages 64-bit integers. Java for example has `long`, which is a signed 64-bit integer. C has `unsigned long long`, which on 64-bit architectures gives you an unsigned 64-bit integer. This means that in Java and C you can create integer values that are much higher that what can be expressed in a `number` in Javascript. This matters when you are creating a JSON API for example.

Answer (score 24):

The size of PHP ints is [platform dependent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is
>   platform-dependent, although a maximum
>   value of about two billion is the
>   usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   PHP does not support unsigned
>   integers. Integer size can be
>   determined using the constant
>   PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using
>   the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP
>   4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

PHP 6 adds "longs" (64 bit ints).

Comment: i don't get these downvotes.. this is a perfectly good answer, even with some extra information thrown in. +1 to correct it.

Comment: This answer originally read "platform *in*dependent" (not dependent).  It also (still) claims that 64-bit ints didn't exist before PHP 6.  This is false.

Comment: PHP 6 never happened though, so it's kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Whether PHP 6 happened or not, this answer claims that earlier versions of PHP had no 64 bit integers, and even implies that PHP versions since have a data type called a "long" - neither is correct.

Answer (score 18):

(a little bit late, but could be useful)

Only trust [PHP_INT_MAX and PHP_INT_SIZE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), this value vary on your arch (32/64 bits) and your OS...

Any other "guess" or "hint" can be false.

Answer (score 7):

Ah I found it: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (2147483647)

https://www.php.net/int

> **Integer overflow**
>
> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

```
<?php
$large_number =  2147483647;
var_dump($large_number);
// output: int(2147483647)

$large_number =  2147483648;
var_dump($large_number);
// output: float(2147483648)
```

Comment: This is what it would be on a 32-bit platform.  Consider also that many people run servers on a 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 3):

It subjects to architecture of the server on which PHP runs. For 64-bit,

`print PHP_INT_MIN . ", ” . PHP_INT_MAX;` yields `-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your OS, but 2147483647 is the usual value, according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: Specifically, it depends on whether you are running on a 32-bit platform or 64-bit.  32-bit is only "usual" in a world where most people run 32-bit servers.  Increasingly this is becoming not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Although `PHP_INT_*` constants exist for a very long time, the same MIN / MAX values could be found programmatically by left shifting until reaching the negative number:

```
$x = 1;
while ($x > 0 && $x <<= 1);
echo "MIN: ", $x;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "MAX: ", ~$x;
```