# PHP variable not incremented

Tags: php

I have a small code as part of a huge file as follows:

```
if(($lastLogTime + $logOffset)>= $text1)
{
    echo $text1.'<br>';

    $uptime=$uptime + (($text1 - $lastLogTime)/60000);
    echo ($text1 - $lastLogTime).'<br>';
    fwrite($fd, $uptime.',');
    echo $uptime.'<br><br>';

    $lastLogTime = ($lastLogTime + 1800000);
    echo $lastLogTime.' ME <br>';
}
```

The weird part is the output for the final `$lastLogTime` is NOT getting added by the `1800000` OR a variable called `$logInterval = 1800000` which was initialized earlier.

The output is

```
1298083876650     -  i.e lastLogtime
1298083877661     - text1

1011              - the difference
0.01685           - uptime

1298085676650 ME  - damn ! doesn't get added by 1800000
```

NEW EDIT :

I solved it ! bad answers guys.. Thanks for the time anyways.

Am i the only one facing weird shhit like this ?

Comment: Your first line is not marked up as code.

Comment: i hav no idea y it wasn't marked ! wat output are u getting ? i still can't get it wrkin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with this:
[What's the maximum size for an int in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-int-in-php)

Check out the php date function.  Though working with dates can be tedious, converting everything to seconds normally isn't the best approach.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: AS is said, it's a huge file and timestamps MORE than 1298085676650 + 1800000    ARE getting displayed later after the loop execution !!

Comment: COuld you gimme a code that achieves this in a different way?

Comment: Use date, then strtotime for comparisons.  Here's a decent explanation: http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html