# PHP Session Variables Using Conditional Statement to Reverse values

Tags: php

I was able to use these Stack questions to implement [file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents) and [is_numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649752/php-is-numeric-or-preg-match-0-9-validation) to have the following code successfully provide me a distance in a numerical value between two lat/long points.  If the system I'm sending the values to cannot provide a time it outputs a [FAILED] and then I display the text "Unroutable".

This is my working code:

```
  $distance = file_get_contents("http://myserver.com/geo/traveltimes.php?start=".$row["Lat"].",".$row["Lon"]."&dest=".$user["Latitude"].",".$user["Longitude"]."");     

  $row["Distance"] = is_numeric($distance) ? $distance : "Unroutable";
```

I'd like as a last ditch effort to reverse the 'start' & 'dest' values to try to see if I can return some numerical results that way.

What is the best way to "trap" a non-numerical value like the [FAILED] and reverse these and THEN display Unroutable if no numerical value is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for an `if` statement?:

```
$distance = file_get_contents("http://myserver.com/geo/traveltimes.php?start=".$row["Lat"].",".$row["Lon"]."&dest=".$user["Latitude"].",".$user["Longitude"]."");     

if (!is_numeric($distance)) {
    $distance = file_get_contents("http://myserver.com/geo/traveltimes.php?start=".$user["Latitude"].",".$user["Longitude"]."&dest=".$row["Lat"].",".$row["Lon"].""); 
}

$row["Distance"] = is_numeric($distance) ? $distance : "Unroutable";
```