# PHP preg_match for validating 10 digit mobile number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate 10 digits mobile number using PHP function preg_match. The below code does not produce any output.

Is it the regex wrong? or I am using it incorrectly.

I was expecting `Hi True` in the output. if it matches or `Hi False` if it does not match.

```
<?php
$value = '9987199871';
$mobileregex = "/^[1-9][0-9]{10}$/" ;  
echo "Hi " . preg_match($mobileregex, $value) === 1; // @debug
?>
```

regex taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649835/4050261

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex you stated will match *eleven* digits, not ten.  Since all Indian mobile numbers start with 9,8,7, or 6, we can use the following regex:

```
^[6-9][0-9]{9}$
```

Here is your code snippet updated:

```
$value = '9987199871';
$mobileregex = "/^[6-9][0-9]{9}$/" ;  
echo "Hi " . preg_match($mobileregex, $value) === 1;
```

Note that the above regex is still probably far from the best we could do in terms of validation, but it is at least a start.

Comment: I am validating Indian Mobile Number.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Regex suggested in this answer. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813226/4050261

Comment: Except that it appears to be wrong [according to this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India) which states that Indian cell numbers can also begin with 6.

Comment: 6 is used for the pager. Thanks for pointing out this. Will use your method.

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha Feel free to page me if you have a follow up question :-)

Answer (score 7):

The following code snippet will check if the mobile number digits are within 10-15 digits including '+' at the start and followed by a non-zero first digit.

Regular expression

```
"/^[+]?[1-9][0-9]{9,14}$/"
```

Code snippet

```
// Validation for the mobile field.
function validateMobileNumber($mobile) {
  if (!empty($mobile)) {
    $isMobileNmberValid = TRUE;
    $mobileDigitsLength = strlen($mobile);
    if ($mobileDigitsLength < 10 || $mobileDigitsLength > 15) {
      $isMobileNmberValid = FALSE;
    } else {
      if (!preg_match("/^[+]?[1-9][0-9]{9,14}$/", $mobile)) {
        $isMobileNmberValid = FALSE;
      }
    }
    return $isMobileNmberValid;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**^**     symbol of the regular expression denotes the start 
**[+]?**    ensures that a single(or zero) + symbol is allowed at the start
**[1-9]**    make sure that the first digit will be a non zero number
**[0-9]{9,14}**   will make sure that there is 9 to 14 digits
**$**   denotes the end

Answer (score 1):

```
$mob = "9513574562";
if(preg_match("/^\d+\.?\d*$/",$mob) && strlen($mob)==10){

echo 1;

}else{

 echo 0;

}
```

preg_match() checking it is integer or not and in strlen() it is checking no of digit in this string. If 2 condition satisfy then it is a 10 digit valid mobile no

Comment: preg_match() checking it is integer or not  and in strlen() it is checking no of digit in this string. If 2 condition satisfy then it is a 10 digit valid mobile no .

Comment: Thanks @Milan Krushna but I meant editing your answer

Comment: I meant that you should edit your answer adding the explanation so that others users read it and vote it. Perhaps the question is validated and you'll get points

Comment: what is the explanation should I add for this answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169582/discussion-between-milan-krushna-and-ignacio-ara).

Answer (score 0):

for pakistani mobile number the regex code will be the following

```
^[9][2][3][0-9]{9}$
```

Comment: Why do you put single digit in character class? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: because we needed 923 fixed digits in front 3 places

Comment: First 3 digits must be 923

Comment: So, `^923[0-9]{9}$` matches the same thing and is more readable. But this doesn't answer the question.