# How to validate Indian Mobile number Contact Form 7 in WordPress?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to validate Indian mobile numbers. The format of the mobile number is as follows:

9775876662, 8156652458, 7596658556, 6655485568

The regEx that is below:

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ){
    $pattern = '%^[+]?' // + sign
        . '(?:\([0-9]+\)|[0-9]+)' // (1234) or 1234
        . '(?:[/ -]*' // delimiter
        . '(?:\([0-9]+\)|[0-9]+)' // (1234) or 1234
        . ')*$%';
    $result = preg_match( $pattern, trim( $tel ) );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

I want to change the pattern. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wpcf7_is_tel` filter hook.

```
function valid_indian_mobile_number( $result, $tel ) { 
    $result = preg_match( '/^[6-9][0-9]{9}$/', $tel );
    return $result; 
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'valid_indian_mobile_number', 10, 2 );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [regular expression for Indian mobile numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers/)
- [PHP preg_match for validating 10 digit mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247396/php-preg-match-for-validating-10-digit-mobile-number/)