# PHP strtotime returning false for UTC time

Tags: php, utc, strtotime

My colleague and I are obtaining different results from some unit tests that use strtotime.

The discrepancy originates in this line:

```
$value = strtotime('2050-05-01T20:10:29.410Z');
```

on my machine, this result returns the following:

```
int(2535048629)
```

whereas my colleague's version returns **false**

We are both using PHP version 5.4.14 and PHPUnit 3.724.

Has anyone got any idea what is causing this discrepancy, and is there a more robust approach?

Comment: 32-bit vs 64-bit? Can you verify?

Comment: Ah, I'm 64 bit. he's 32...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because he is on 32-bit and you are on 64-bit machine. See what `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` returns on both machines. More read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-int-in-php).

If you wish to get timestamp on 32-bit machine, you can use DateTime as:

```
$value = new DateTime('2050-05-01T20:10:29.410Z');
echo $value->format('U');  // returns 2535048629 as string
```

or format inputed timestamp as:

```
$value = new DateTime('@2535048629');
echo $value->format('r'); // Sun, 01 May 2050 20:10:29 +0000
```

instead of `date('r', '2535048629');` which will not work on 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely related to 32-bit vs 64-bit. Timestamps in the year 2050 are larger than 32 bits.

Comment: in the end I awarded the answer to Glavic, given that his explanation adds a little more detail for others that may encounter the same issue.