# php displays wrong date in php for 31-12-9999

Tags: php, mktime

When I try to execute following statement in PHP

`echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0,12, 31, 9999));`

PHP returns following date

**Result Jan 01 1970 00:00:00**

I also did try using following strtotime function but the result is same

`echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", strtotime('2999-12-31'));`

**Result: Jan 01 1970 00:00:00**

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP strtotime returning false for UTC time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547043/php-strtotime-returning-false-for-utc-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The years 9999 and 2999 are out of range for UNIX timestamps (the format returned by `strtotime()` and `gmmktime()`). The maximum valid value is INT_MAX, `0x7fffffff` (around January 18th, 2038).

Answer (score 0):

The max date the `gmdate` function can use is 19 Jan. 2038; trying to use a date beyond that just doesn't compute (literally), so PHP returns the base Unix date that you're seeing in your result.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php.