# abs + strtotime give the same result for different date subtractions

Tags: php, strtotime

I've got this code:

```
<?php

$data = array(array("1","name1","2050-10-10"),array("2","name1","2051-10-10"));
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$x = 2;

foreach($data as $day)
{
$interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day[$x]));
$interval[] = $day[$x];
}

var_dump($interval);

?>
```

I tried it on my own server :

It returns :

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
  [0]=> int(1418338800) 
  [1]=> string(10) "2050-10-10" 
  [2]=> int(1418338800) 
  [3]=> string(10) "2051-10-10"    
} 
}
```

but http://writecodeonline.com/php/ returns :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1130716800)
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2050-10-10"
  [2]=>
  int(1162252800)
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2051-10-10"
}
```

I don't understand why the value 1418338800 stays the same and I wonder how I could solve this problem!

Thank you a lot in advance

Following the @Jonathan Kuhn advice:

```
<?php

echo strtotime("2051-10-10");
echo strtotime("2050-10-10");
echo strtotime("2040-10-10");
echo strtotime("2039-10-10");
echo strtotime("2038-10-10");
echo strtotime("2037-10-10");
echo strtotime("2036-10-10");

?>
```

It returns:

```
empty line
empty line
empty line
empty line
empty line
2138738400
2107202400
```

The problem came from the 32 bit system.

Comment: Your question indicates that there are two different dates being used, but in your code both of them say "2050-10-10".  Are you sure you pasted the code correctly?

Comment: Integer overflow maybe? 32 bit systems run out of timestamps on `03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038`

Comment: Try checking that the timestamps for both dates aren't the same and what timestamp do you get for each date?

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn I didn't know about 32 bits systems timestamps limitation... Could I find a workaround?

Comment: From what I see the code works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GD3PaX

Comment: @user1719210 - workround is either to switch to 64-bit PHP, or to start using DateTime objects

Comment: On a 32bit system, don't use timestamps for dates past 2038. You can use the datetime class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Comment: Thank you a lot !! Is there any other things I need to take care of on a 32 bit system? Is there a good documentation about the limitations? For anybody else having this issue, I found this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of **[PHP strtotime returning false for UTC time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547043/php-strtotime-returning-false-for-utc-time)**