# NumberFormatter with PHP maximum number possible

Tags: php, icu, numberformatter

What is the biggest number, which is possible to use with NumberFormatter in PHP with the newest ICU version?

I tested some numbers on 3v4l.org or on viper-7.com and

999899999999999999 was the maximum. 
I tested it for some other languages, too.

For 999999999999999999 I got nine hundred ninety-nine quadrillion and the the last 15 numbers wasn't spellout.

**php code**

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-cardinal");
echo $formatter->format(999899999999999999);
```

**test results**

https://3v4l.org/YXU5d for 999899999999999999

[http://codepad.viper-7.com/traNvh](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pHw2PP) for 999899999999999999

**Edit:** First I had 99899999999999999 and now I have updated it to 999899999999999999 with a new nine at the beginning

Comment: haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: @Dagon I am not sure with my answer and didn't find a real source.

Comment: Number in php is "integer" or "float". Integers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/670668/4621324 also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php For floats `The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).`