# Can't install php7.0 on debian 7 64 bits

Tags: php, 64-bit

I have some problems with installing a php 7 64bits or any php that uses 64bits .

I require 64 bits because the value that is returning to my DB is too big for a 32 bits and I can't make it smaller to fit for a 32 bits .

Can anyone give me an tutorial for a installation of php 7 64bits for Debian 7 ?

I tried using this :

`apt-get install -y php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-cgi but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: php7.0-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

And this is the repository `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `I can't make it smaller to fit for a 32 bits` can you explain that?

Comment: You can only install PHP 7 x64 when your OS and CPU architecture is 64 bits.

Comment: @JOUM the value that is returning is too big for php 32 bits to handle it .

Comment: @CharlotteDunois my os is a debian 7 64 bits .

Comment: Dont now what you are trying, so you reached the PHP_MAX_INTEGER size?

Comment: @JOUM Yes , that's what I wanted to say .. Sorry i am in a hurry .

Comment: Forgt it. Wrong page :)

Comment: @JOUM Tbh I don't know it either I saw it on a documentation page and tried it , i also just tried `apt-get install php7.0` and i recieve the same result.

Comment: @JOUM `apt-get` prompts you if there are additional dependencies needed and by using `-y` you skip the prompt and `apt-get` will automatically download and install the dependencies.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois Thanks, read it seconds ago too

Comment: Does anyone have a clue why i recieve broken packages ?

Comment: Unmet dependencies. Depending on your current server setup, you either need to install the libapache mod or php7 fpm. Additional to it you need to install php7-common.

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-common : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u11 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are using a Debian Linux install that is 64-bit. You can find out by running "uname -a". If you see "x86_64" in the response you are good.

Second, do you really need PHP 7 on Debian 7?

- If PHP 5/Debian 7 can work, you can do a simple "apt-get install php5" to install PHP. I would recommend using the Dotdeb repository. It contains more recent versions of PHP compared to the standard Debian repos. The following URL will contain instructions on how to set it up on your server. https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/
- If you can upgrade to Debian 8, Dotdeb repo already has PHP7. You can simply do "apt-get install php7" to install it.

Third, if you really want PHP 7 on Debian 7, you can compile it yourself. The following link has instructions on how to do that. https://github.com/drj-io/php7-debian-build

Comment: The thing is i don't really need php 7 i need a PHP that is using 64 bits . Because my PHP_MAX_INTEGER size is too big for 32 bits.

Comment: @Sebastian Neamtu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-int-in-php