# Laravel eloquent model has incorrect primary key value using custom table and primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm migrating an app from straight PHP to using Laravel. The current users table is called `Person` with the primary key `person_id` which is of `unsigned bigint(20)` type.

I've updated my App\User model with the following:

```
protected $table = 'Person';
protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';
```

Whenever I make a request and inspect `Auth->user()`, the `person_id` is always the wrong value. My expected id is `4294967410` but it's returning `2147483647`. All other attributes on the user are correct (email, name, etc...).

I'm very stuck as to why this is the case. I'm using a fresh install of laravel.

Comment: Can you share the migration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related if not duplicate of [What's the maximum size for an int in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-int-in-php)

You are getting `PHP_INT_MAX` which is 2147483647 on 32 bit machines.

For example on my Mac the int limit is:

```
Psy Shell v0.9.4 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> echo PHP_INT_MAX
9223372036854775807⏎
```

Solution is to use 64 bit machine with 64 bit PHP build.