# skip parameter value of a function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, oop

Let suppose I have a function:

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 200,$type='result')
{
    //Query generation according to above parameters
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
}
```

This function is been used to many pages. Now, I want to skip the parameter `$limit` From function.  That means I don't want to give `$limit` value but I need all data from database.

So what happens is if I have data like 600 and I don't know how many data I have, I don't give any parameter value to function (so by default it will take 500 data). **But here I need all data** so how can I manage this situation?

Comment: See marvinIsSacul's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922628/1020526) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html passing in `NULL` to the `limit` method as the first parameter will cause the limit statement to **not** limit anything - hence returning all of the rows (see on [github](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/d0d4548c4b6917a3e389fb97acbc6123e2060ae2/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1331)):

```
public function limit($value, $offset = 0)
{
    is_null($value) OR $this->qb_limit = (int) $value;
    empty($offset) OR $this->qb_offset = (int) $offset;
    return $this;
}
```

So in short if you want to skip the `$limit` parameter try setting its value to `NULL`. Like so...

```
public function __getalldata($tablename, $tablefield=array(), $orderbyfield = 'id', $ascdesc = 'desc', $limit = NULL, $type='result')
{
    // Query generation according to above parameters
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
}
```

Comment: If you set the value to null, it will be converted to 0, which won't return any results, the OP wants to return all the results

Comment: not that's totally inaccurate @chinloyal. in fact the default value of the `limit` parameters are `NULL`. go ahead and check it, you'll see. and I am referring to CI>=3

Comment: setting a value to null to evade a value is a hack, at best a workaround. Designing your code with conditional statements is cleaner, reliable, and good practice.

Comment: I tried it by giving value to `NULL` and working as expected. returns all result

Comment: @revo using null to evade a value is NEVER a handy feature.

Comment: @Xavier yea of course. but we have to remember that CodeIgniter is a framework (and a framework is designed to remove boiler plate coding). so it probably has conditional statements under the hood which handle the NULL cases.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul making conclusions based on "probably" is bad advice.

Comment: @Xavier you're correct. but the as you can see from my answer (which was edited by revo to include the CodeIgniter code), NULL cases are definitely handled. Hence us as users needn't

Comment: @marvinIsSacul it is bad practice to evade values by assigning null. One should design functions to handle the conditions. the OP's question is clearly a condition solution.

Comment: now that right there @Xavier is a matter of style and preference. take a look at the CodeIgniter source code on GitHub and you will see that a lot of their methods/functions have `NULL` default parameter values.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul I did not state it was bad practice to assign null values, I stated it was bad practice to evade values using null. big difference there. furthermore, one should rely on documentation of features to understand bad and good practice.

Comment: [this article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/85-why-null-values-should-not-be-used-in-a-database-unless-required.htm) illustrates my point well

Comment: @Xavier In your own answer you're checking for `$limit` variable and left it for OP to decide about the inner condition so that they could type `if (is_int($limit)) {...` which means if `$limit` is set to a non-integer value like `NULL`, the limit clause is off the query. That is called *duplicating* since `NULL` checking is correctly handled within the original `limit()` method of the query builder. Relying on such `NULL` handling isn't a bad practice rather it is so expected `->limit(null)`.

Comment: @revo if you want to discuss my answer, please do so on my answer. this is turning into a discussion.

Comment: @Xavier I'm neither supposed to keep this up nor seeking for a resolution and the article you are pointing to is about a thought on NULL value type in table column definitions. This is PHP.

Comment: @Xavier like I said, what you are stressing so much on is really just a preference. at the end of the day, it is up to the programming team how they would like to skip method parameters. Because as a matter of fact, there a probably a million different ways to do so.

Comment: @Xavier, the article is about allowing the storage of NULL values in a database and so does not illustrate your point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the default value of `$limit = 200` is already used in a number of places in the application. So the goal is to bypass the default when you want all the matching records. My suggestion is to simply pass the value `0` (zero) when you want them all. Then the only a small code change is required in the class method.

```
public function __getalldata($tablename, $tablefield=array(), $orderbyfield = 'id',
                             $ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 200,$type='result')
{
    if($limit > 0)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    }

    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)                
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to clarify the IF clause with `{...}` in this example case

Comment: I like this idea because it shortens the code from the previous `if else` answers, but you really need those curly braces.

Comment: @Martin, I knew someone would comment on the missing braces. :) Technically you don't need them. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) does not use them for a single statement. The use of curly braces is often defined as a MUST item in style guides e.g. PSR-2. But guides are a prefered presentation, not functional requisite.  That said, using braces all the time is a good habit to have.

Comment: @DFriend agreed, using them always is best practice and good advice. I have already edited your answer, just waiting for peer review.

Comment: In the interest of global peace and goodwill toward all, I've added braces. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = '',$type='result')
{
    //Query generation according to above parameters
    if($limit == '') {
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->get();
} else {
$data = $this->db
             ->select($tablefield)
             ->from($tablename)
             ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
             ->limit($limit)
             ->get();
}
    return $data->$type();
}
```

Did you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

You can used bigint max values `18446744073709551615` to retrieve all data from `MySQL`.

So your function should look like this

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 18446744073709551615,$type='result')
{
    //Query generation according to above parameters
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
}
```

Comment: [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#sa64618991) make sense as to retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, we can use some large number for the second parameter.

Comment: @TarangP Yeah, you can use it in your function as well. It will won't effect on query execution time as well. So it will take same time as select query for execution.

Comment: yep would work on `MySQL`. but the solution is **not** portable. Because what about `mssql`, etc. ???

Comment: @marvinIsSacul As per OP code, He was asking for `MySQL` not for `mssql`. Because `mssql` use `TOP` rather than `LIMIT`.

Comment: did he now? where in his question is there `MySQL` ?

Comment: @marvinIsSacul you can clearly see `limit` parameter in OP query. So there is no point to argument I guess.

Comment: yea you're right. but nevertheless the solution is still **not** portable - which defeats one of the  purposes of a framework. if you use the CodeIgniter `limit` method on `MySQL` and on `mssql` is will generate a different SQL command, depending on the Server. But as users of the framework we need not worry about this.

Comment: but with your solution, using big ints on `mssql`, etc. might not work. what then???

Comment: @marvinIsSacul I have follow what OP want. Not possibility. So point is, OP want it for `Codeigniter` and `MySQL`.

Comment: oh okay. I understand.

Answer (score -1):

> Note my main answer is at the bottom (***IF you can't edit this function***) but I have put in alternative answers as am unclear from OP as to if the function can/should be edited.

## Edit this function

Your declared function has:

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,...,$limit = 200 ...){ ... }
```

Where the reference given in [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922628/3536236) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922696/3536236) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922617/3536236) appearing to be adjusting this default value - the simplest solution is to NOT edit the *default* but set a *special case*  and explicitly check for if `$limit` is exactly (and only) `null`.

**To clarify:**
[PHP will use an explicitly set `NULL` value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) over any default value (in this case, `200`).

So;

```
// within the function
if($limit !== null) {
    //use limit in your PDO
}
```

This **does not** convert if `$limit == 0` or other type-juggling cases, common to PHP

This above means that if **no** `$limit` value is given then default of `200` is used. If an explicit `NULL` value is given, that will be used instead.

---

**Code**

> *Please note this code is for example only and can probably be simplified further to better follow DRY patterns, but I don't know enough about CodeIgniter to do this here and now.*

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 200,$type='result')
{
    //Query generation according to above parameters
    if($limit !== null){
        $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    }
    else { 
        $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->get();    
    }
    return $data->$type();
}
```

---

## If you can't edit the function

I'm unclear on if you can (or want) to edit the function itself, if you're using Codeigniter, so instead simply refer an automatic value to the function arguments to return every valud row, no matter what (in effect removing the case for limit.

To do this use the [PHP Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) `PHP_INT_SIZE` or `PHP_INT_MAX` which will return exactly that value. [Reading this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-value-for-an-int-in-php) tells you more about this, but these constants should be self explanatory, as the maximum int values.

If a MySQL `LIMIT` exceeds the rows returned, this has no effect, so by setting this to a maximal value, it will always exceed the rows returned and/or the rows usable by the resulting page output.

Therefore:

```
 $var = __getalldata("table",[0=>'columnname'],'id','desc',PHP_INT_MAX,'result');
```

Will return you every row within the PHP Integer limit of [2,147,483,647] or [9,223,372,036,854,775,807], depending on your system (32bit or 64bit).

> *And let's face it -- if 2 billion is not enough of a limit, you need to face you have some serious problems with your SQL query `;-)`*

Comment: So you basically just used a condition statement. There are already two answers that do the same thing.

Comment: Please see `IF you can't edit the function`, @Xavier

Comment: There is no point. The answer is acceptable. My point is that there are already two answers before you that are the same. Becomes repetitive to offer the same answer at this point.

Comment: @Xavier it is not the same answer -- my answer revolves around using a PHP Constant to place the maximum value of an `INT`. Please read my answer.

Answer (score -2):

That is easy with the use of an `if` statement. Just check to see if a condition is true for your `limit`, if not resolve to `else`. Like so:

```
public function __getalldata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 200,$type='result')
{
    if () // check $limit condition here
    {
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
    }
    else {
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->get();
    return $data->$type();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am not sure what your conditions for the `$limit` variable are, so just enter them in the `if` statement's arguments.

Comment: what if i have `20+` function's like this. i cant use `if else` everywhere

Comment: @TarangP is that not why you are using object oriented programming? to be able to reuse your functions?

Comment: @TarangP why not make these values an extended class, to inherit from?

Comment: The other answer is not a copy of yours. Don't write rude comments, instead flag things you think are wrong.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Rude comments? I was asking questions to suggest some ideas. Not sure how you took that as rude.