# Decode a CS:GO match sharing code with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, byte, steam

I am trying to build a function which decodes a CS:GO match sharing code. I have seen enough examples but everyhting is in JS or C# but nothing in PHP.

I took the [akiver demo manager](https://github.com/akiver/CSGO-Demos-Manager/blob/7abb325ad3663732ca585addee52383a78751314/Core/ShareCode.cs#L79) as an example and i tried to replicate it in PHP. I am going bit blind because i have no idea what is the output on a certain points so i can only hope that the result will be what i expect it to be. I think i am on the right path, the problem comes when the bytes have to be created/interpeted/converted to the desire outcome.

The code that should be decoded is the following: `'CSGO-oPRbA-uTQuR-UFkiC-hYWMB-syBcO'` (`$getNextGame` variable)

The result should be **3418217537907720662**

My code so far:

```
 /**
 * @param $getNextGame
 * @return array
 */
 public function decodeDemoCode(string $getNextGame): array
 {
     $shareCodePattern = "/CSGO(-?[\w]{5}){5}$/";
     if (preg_match($shareCodePattern, $getNextGame) === 1) {
        $result = [];
        $bigNumber = 0;
        $matchIdBytes = $outcomeIdBytes = $tvPortIdBytes = [];
        $dictionary = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefhijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789";
        $dictionaryLength = strlen($dictionary);

        $changedNextGame = str_replace(array("CSGO", "-"), "", $getNextGame);
        $chars = array_reverse(str_split($changedNextGame));
        foreach ($chars as $char) {
           $bigNumber = ($bigNumber * $dictionaryLength) + strpos($dictionary, $char);
        }
     }
 }
```

This brings me back something like that:

```
1.86423701402E+43 (double)
```

Then i have the following:

```
$packed = unpack("C*", $bigNumber);
$reversedPacked = array_reverse($packed);
```

and this brings the following back:

```
array(17 items)
   0 => 51 (integer)
   1 => 52 (integer)
   2 => 43 (integer)
   3 => 69 (integer)
   4 => 50 (integer)
   5 => 48 (integer)
   6 => 52 (integer)
   7 => 49 (integer)
   8 => 48 (integer)
   9 => 55 (integer)
   10 => 51 (integer)
   11 => 50 (integer)
   12 => 52 (integer)
   13 => 54 (integer)
   14 => 56 (integer)
   15 => 46 (integer)
   16 => 49 (integer)
```

Now here i am not really sure what to do because i do not completely understand C# and i have never worked with bytes in PHP before.

Generally the return type should be an array and would look something like that:

```
$result = [
   matchId => 3418217537907720662,
   reservationId => 3418217537907720662,
   tvPort => 55788
];
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: It may help if you showed the actual input to the function (`$getNextGame`).

Comment: i may have named it wrong by putting the word "get" in it, but it is just a string. I am going to update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a PHP class which makes that possible:

[CS:GO ShareCode Decoder PHP](https://github.com/AKaravas/csgo-sharecode-decoder)

The first problem you have to solve is the returned double value. PHP has limitation when it comes to big integers. More to that here [What is the maximum value for an integer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-value-for-an-int-in-php).

Because of this limitation you are losing precision leading to inaccurate results. In order to solve this problem you will have to use one of these libraries [GMB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). What these libraries do, is to give you back the result as a **string** which solves the double value you got.

So your code has to look something like that:

```
foreach ($chars as $char) {
      $bigNumber = gmp_add(
         gmp_mul($bigNumber,$dictionaryLength),
         strpos($dictionary,$char)
     );
}
json_encode($bigNumber);
$result = json_decode($bigNumber, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

This will give you back the following `"18642370140230194654275126136176397505221000"`

You do not really need the PHP [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) functions since the results can be generated without them. The next step is to convert your number to hexadecimal. You can do that with the following:

```
$toHex = gmp_strval(gmp_init($number, 10), 16);
```

Again you need to use the gmp library in order to get the desired value. What you do, is to make sure that the result is a string and then you convert your number's base from 10 to 16 which is the equivalent of hexadecimal. The results is the following:

```
"d6010080bdf26f2fbf0100007cf76f2f5188"
```

The next step is to convert the hex value to an array of byte integers. It looks like this:

```
$bytes = [];
$byteArray= str_split($toHex, 2);
foreach ($byteArray as $byte) {
    $bytes[] = (int)base_convert($byte, 16, 10);
}
```

What you do here is to split the array to every two chars. The `$byteArray` variable looks like this (before it enters the foreach loop)

```
array(18 items)
   0 => 'd6' (2 chars) 1 => '01' (2 chars) 2 => '00' (2 chars) 3 => '80' (2 chars)
   4 => 'bd' (2 chars) 5 => 'f2' (2 chars) 6 => '6f' (2 chars) 7 => '2f' (2 chars)
   8 => 'bf' (2 chars) 9 => '01' (2 chars) 10 => '00' (2 chars) 11 => '00' (2 chars)
   12 => '7c' (2 chars) 13 => 'f7' (2 chars) 14 => '6f' (2 chars) 15 => '2f' (2 chars)
   16 => '51' (2 chars) 17 => '88' (2 chars)
```

Now you will have to convert each entry into integer. Since the results are not that big anymore you can change the base of your values with the [base_convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function. The base is 16 (hex) and you will have to change it back to 10. The results `$bytes` after the foreach loop looks like this:

```
array(18 items)
   0 => 214 (integer) 1 => 1 (integer) 2 => 0 (integer) 3 => 128 (integer)
   4 => 189 (integer) 5 => 242 (integer) 6 => 111 (integer) 7 => 47 (integer)
   8 => 191 (integer) 9 => 1 (integer) 10 => 0 (integer) 11 => 0 (integer)
   12 => 124 (integer) 13 => 247 (integer) 14 => 111 (integer) 15 => 47 (integer)
   16 => 81 (integer) 17 => 136 (integer)
```

Now you have to define which bytes are responsible for each result.

```
$matchIdBytes = array_reverse(array_slice($bytes, 0, 8));
$reservationIdBytes = array_reverse(array_slice($bytes, 8, 8));
$portBytes = array_reverse(array_slice($bytes, 16, 2));
```

- For the match id you will have to get the first 8 entries and the reverse the array
- For the reservation id you will have to get the next 8 entries starting from the 8th entry and reverse the array
- For the port you will have to get the last 2 entries and reverse the array

Now you will have to return the value

```
  return [
       'matchId' =>  $this->getResultFromBytes($matchIdBytes),
       'reservationId' => $this->getResultFromBytes($reservationIdBytes),
       'tvPort' =>  $this->getResultFromBytes($portBytes)
  ];
```

The `getResultFromBytes()` function:

```
 **
 * @param array $bytes
 * @return string
 */
 public function getResultFromBytes(array $bytes): string
 {
    $chars = array_map("chr", $bytes);
    $bin = implode($chars);
    $hex = bin2hex($bin);
    return gmp_strval($this->gmp_hexDec($hex));
  }

 /**
 * @param $n
 * @return string
 */
public function gmp_hexDec($n): string
{
    $gmp = gmp_init(0);
    $multi = gmp_init(1);
    for ($i=strlen($n)-1;$i>=0;$i--,$multi=gmp_mul($multi, 16)) {
        $gmp = gmp_add($gmp, gmp_mul($multi, hexdec($n[$i])));
    }
    return $gmp;
}
```

Best regards