# Different Value of left and right shift in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, bit-shift

Below is the left shift code in c# and php7.

Why and how to match PHP output with C# output?

Thanks in advance.

### C#

```
    var ret = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    var a=ret << 8;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
```

### Output

```
        4294967040
```

where as

### PHP

```
    $ret = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    $a=$ret << 8;
    echo $a;
```

### Output

```
       1099511627520
```

Comment: I'm going to guess this is because C# and PHP have different max values for the data types you're using.

Comment: See [What's the maximum value for an int in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-value-for-an-int-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the var keyword, use explicitly long instead of it:

```
long ret = 0xFFFFFFFF;
long a = ret << 8;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The var will use a 32 bit integer not a 64 bit integer.

Comment: The long datatype represents a 64-bit signed integer.

Comment: My mistake. Could you add an explanation why bit shifting a `UInt32` (which hex literals are when using `var`) produces the "wrong" result, while a long is "right"?

Comment: The UInt32 value type represents unsigned integers with values ranging from 0 to 4,294,967,295. The result (1099511627520) is greater than the maximum value of an UInt32.

Comment: Thanks 
In PHP
    $ret = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    $a=($ret << 8 ) & 0xFFFFFFFF;//convet to 32 bit integer
    echo $a;