# Int casting gives wrong number on WAMP

Tags: php, casting, integer, php-5.6

I have some legacy code on a **Windows** machine running **PHP 5.6** that we will be dismissing but I need to do some migrations from.

I have trivial bit of code that is quite mistifying to me.
I've simplified it for this question, but the behavior is the same.

```
$a = "3109584483";
$b = (int) $a;
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

And this is the output:

```
string(10) "3109584483"
int(2147483647)
```

I have looked at all the similar questions about this, but they all mention

- Casting a float (not my case)
- Getting the result in a non-10 base (I tried converting `2147483647` from and to common bases like HEX, OCT and BIN, but I can't seem to find a match that would justify the result)

What is the reason of this wrong casting?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You're hitting the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer

Comment: It's worth noting that I tried the same piece of code on a UNIX machine and it returns the correct value. That's why I thought to emphazise that the problem is on Windows.

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/670668/476

Comment: Ah, there it is, missed it.  Was the downvote really necessary though? Anyway, thanks guys. :)