bitmasking for values over 2³²
I know PHP integers are between -2³² and 2³² and unsigned integers don't exist. Would there be a way to bitmask for values over 2³²? I'm looking for a way to implement a effecient Set class using bit wise operators and being able to cater for more that 32 elements (64 as there are 64 bits in an integer)

Actually they're between -2^31 and 2^31-1.

Use an array of integers.

Replace 31 with 63 for 64-bit systems. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-value-for-an-int-in-php

echo strlen(sprintf('%b', -1)); // 64

This sounds like premature micro-optimization. What performance issues are you currently encountering?

You know instead of integers you can use binary strings of arbitrary length, chr($some_8bit_value), bitwise functions, and some simple math and have a bitfield of functionally unlimited size.

Consider using a string, e.g.: $set = str_repeat('0', 100); allocates 100 elements. $set[$i] = '1'; adds an element to the set.

I've found out that although PHP does not have unsigend integers it really doesn't matter for the left shift operator (<<). It would deal with both positive and negative numbers. This can be shown by outputting a hex representation of the numbers. Here is a simple code:
$total = 0;
for($i=$p=1; $p; $i++, $p<<=1) {
    printf("%d: 0x%x(%d)<br>", $i, $p, $p);
    $total += $p;
}
printf("Full set: 0x%x($d)<br>", $total, $total);

On a 64-bit PHP version this will output all the possible bit positions:
1: 0x1(1)
2: 0x2(2)
3: 0x4(4)
4: 0x8(8)
5: 0x10(16)
...
62: 0x2000000000000000(2305843009213693952)
63: 0x4000000000000000(4611686018427387904)
64: 0x8000000000000000(-9223372036854775808)

Followed by would considered as a full 64-element set:
Full set: 0xffffffffffffffff(-1)

That half of the numbers would be displayed as negative numbers (2-complements) is irrelevant.
To test the maximal set size any PHP installation could offer use this;
echo "set size:" . PHP_INT_SIZE*8 . '<br>';

A simple implementation of a fast-ish set class with named elements could look like this:
class Set
{
    protected /*unsigned*/ int $store;
    protected int $position = 1;
    protected array $names = [];
    public function __construct( /*unsigned*/ int $value = 0 ) {
        $this->store = $value;
    }
    public function __addName( mixed $name ): self {
        if($this->position === 0) {
            throw new \RuntimeException( 'Set capacity exceeded' );
        }
        $this->names[$this->position] = $name;
        $this->position <<= 1;

        return $this;
    }
    private function __getBit($flag): /*unsigned*/ int
    {
        if( !$bit=array_search($flag, $this->names) ) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException( 'Invalid flag '. $flag );
        }
        return $bit;
    }
    public function set( mixed $flag ): self
    {
        $bit = $this->__getBit($flag);
        $this->store |= $bit;
        return $this;
    }
    public function unset( mixed $flag ): self
    {
        $bit = $this->__getBit($flag);
        $this->store &= ~$bit;
        return $this;
    }
    public function has( mixed $flag ): bool
    {
        $bit = $this->__getBit($flag);
        return ($this->store & $bit) !== 0;
    }
    public function empty()
    {
        $this->store = 0;
    }
    public function __tostring(): string
    {
        return '(' . implode(',', $this->toArray()) . ')';
    }
    public function toArray(): array
    {
        $flags = [];
        foreach( $this->names as $flag => $name ) {
            if( $this->store & $flag ) {
                $flags[] = $name;
            }
        }
        return $flags;
    }
    public function __serialize():array
    {
        $flags = [];
        foreach( $this->names as $flag => $name ) {
            if( $this->store & $flag ) {
                $flags[] = $name;
            }
        }
        return $flags;
    }
    public function __unserialize(array $flags)
    {
        foreach($flags as $flag) {
            $this-> set( $flag );
        }
    }
}

Which could be used like:
$set = new Set();
$set->__addName( 'FLAG_A' )->__addName( 'FLAG_B' )->__addName( 'FLAG_C' );
$set->set( 'FLAG_A' )->set( 'FLAG_C' );

echo $set . "<br>"; echo 'has FLAG_A:'.($set->has('FLAG_A')?'true':'false') . "<br>";
$set->unset( 'FLAG_A' );
echo $set . "<br>"; echo 'has FLAG_A:'.($set->has('FLAG_A')?'true':'false') . "<br>";
$set->set( 'FLAG_B');
echo $set; // Outputs 'FLAG_A,FLAG_C'

